# Getting data from mysql to popup window

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, popupwindow

I'm using php,html,javascript,mysql.
My functionality goes like this. I have a division made in html which have the data retrieved from database as a list. So, if there are 5 list items each will be having an onclick event, clicking a popup window will be shown. Popup window is shown by javascript. So, i'm finished up to this part. The stage i'm stuck up is i have to get data into that popup window from my mysql tabe. How can i accomplish this,
Guys, please help me out.

I also have a sample site whic looks exactly like my application. Please check it out.

http://yale.roammeo.com/main/#!/list/2011-11-09/12-30/

Popup is not showing any physically existing page. Its just showing a new html page with two divisions in it. How to retrieve data from mysql into this division?

```
<div id="blanket" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="popUpDiv" style="display:none;width:500px;height:400px;">
<div align="left" class="popup_head">
<div align="right" style="float:right;width:10%">
<a href="#" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')" style="color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none">X</a>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
<div align="center" style="padding:10px;">

<form action=""  onSubmit='search()' method="post" name="frmSendMsg">
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it depends on how exactly your javascript popup works.

If the popup shows some physically existing page, then this page should fetch data from mysql just like your main page.

If the popup shows some dynamically js-generated page, you should probably use AJAX techniques, i.e. have some PHP backend which is able to fetch data from mysql and address this backend from javascript. Most modern JS frameworks can do it any way you want (XML, JSON etc.).